# Why are Symfony2 validation propertyPath valus in square brackets?

Tags: symfony

I am validating some values:

```
$collectionConstraint = new Collection(array(
    'email' => array(
        new NotBlank(),
        new Email(),
    ),
    'password'  => array(
         new NotBlank(),
         new MinLength(array('limit' => 6)),
         new MaxLength(array('limit' => 25)),
    ),
));
$data = array('email' => $this->getRequest()->get('email'), 'password' => $this->getRequest()->get('password'));
$errors = $this->get('validator')->validateValue($data, $collectionConstraint);
```

But for some reason the fields (propertyPath) are stored with square brackets - I'd like to understand why Sf does that. I have to manually remove all the brackets which seems absurd so I think I am missing some functionality somewhere.

Dump of $errors:

```
Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolationList Object
(
    [violations:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolation Object
                (
                    [messageTemplate:protected] => This value should not be blank
                    [messageParameters:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [root:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [email] => 
                            [password] => 
                        )

                    [propertyPath:protected] => [email]
                    [invalidValue:protected] => 
                )

            [1] => Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolation Object
                (
                    [messageTemplate:protected] => This value should not be blank
                    [messageParameters:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [root:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [email] => 
                            [password] => 
                        )

                    [propertyPath:protected] => [password]
                    [invalidValue:protected] => 
                )

        )

)
```

Even the toString function is useless.

```
"[email]: This value should not be blank","[password]: This value should not be blank"
```

Answer (score 5):

Property paths can map either to properties or to indices. Consider a class `OptionBag` which implements `\ArrayAccess` and a method `getSize()`.

- The property path `size` refers to `$optionBag->getSize()`
- The property path `[size]` refers to `$optionBag['size']`

In your case, you validate an array. Since array elements are also accessed by index, the resulting property path in the violation contains squared brackets.

**Update:**

You don't have to manually remove the squared brackets. You can use Symfony's PropertyAccess component to map errors to an array with the same structure as your data, for example:

```
$collectionConstraint = new Collection(array(
    'email' => array(
        new NotBlank(),
        new Email(),
    ),
    'password'  => array(
         new NotBlank(),
         new MinLength(array('limit' => 6)),
         new MaxLength(array('limit' => 25)),
    ),
));

$data = array(
    'email' => $this->getRequest()->get('email'), 
    'password' => $this->getRequest()->get('password')
);

$violations = $this->get('validator')->validateValue($data, $collectionConstraint);

$errors = array();
$accessor = $this->get('property_accessor');

foreach ($violations as $violation) {
    $accessor->setValue($errors, $violation->getPropertyPath(), $violation->getMessage());
}

=> array(
    'email' => 'This value should not be blank.',
    'password' => 'This value should have 6 characters or more.',
)
```

This also works with multi-dimensional data arrays. There the property paths will be something like `[author][name]`. The PropertyAccessor will insert the error messages in the same location in the `$errors` array, i.e. `$errors['author']['name'] = 'Message'`.

Comment: How can I benefit from this approach? I could understand that validating nested array could result with indexes within [], but when it's a single index from an array it think it shouldn't have []. Someone who does validation should be aware that is he validating (object or an array).

Comment: If you want to do deterministic error mapping, you need to know that. Consider a form that displays one input for the above getSize() and another for ['size'] (hypothetical). For mapping the errors, you need to know exactly to which field each violation belongs to.

Comment: What kind of exception class can handel an array of errors ? In our case?

Comment: @BernhardSchussek The solution is not correct. Multiple violations for the same field will be overriden. Only the last one is kept.

Answer (score 1):

`PropertyAccessor's` `setValue` is no real help because it cannot handle multiple violations for a single field. For instance, a field might be shorter than a constraint length and also contain illegal characters. For this, we would have two error messages.

I had to create my own code:

```
$messages = [];

foreach ($violations as $violation) {

    $field = substr($violation->getPropertyPath(), 1, -1);
    $messages[] = [$field => $violation->getMessage()];
}

$output = [
    'name' => array_unique(array_column($messages, 'name')),
    'email' => array_unique(array_column($messages, 'email')),
];

return $output;
```

We manually strip the `[]` characters from the property path and create an 
array of arrays of fields and corresponding messages. Later we transform the 
array to group the messages by fields.

```
$session = $request->getSession();
$session->getFlashBag()->setAll($messages);
```

In the controller, we add the messages to the flash bag.